# javascript ternary operator error

Tags: javascript

I am confused when the ternary operator behaves differently than I expected. Here is my code:

```
function zeroCol() {
    var arr = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        (i % 2 == 0) ? arr.push(0) : arr.push(1)

        return arr.join(" ")
    }
}
console.log(zeroCol())
```

It prints 0 instead of 01010 that I expected. But that works using if/else,why?

```
if(i%2==0) arr.push(0) 
arr.push(1);
```

Comment: Because you do `return` in  very first iteration.

Comment: Work on your `{` and `}`

Comment: That's not a very proper if statement, add some brackets, and a else, and you'll get the same result.

Comment: The second code block misses the `else` part.

Comment: Use an if/else! That is a bad use of a ternary operator. There is no need for an if/else either.

Comment: This question is NOT off-topic, but it is a simple mistake and leaving it on the site wouldn't help someone else looking for information. If OP got his/her answer, this should be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your life easier, remove it :

```
function zeroCol() {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        arr.push(i % 2);
    }
    return arr.join(" ")
}
```

Notice that `return` stops the function, so, put it outside of the for loop.

To build on [dfsq's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22150184/javascript-ternary-operator-error#comment33612291_22150370), notice that this function is useless in its current state. Indeed, the loop's limit and the divisor are both hard coded. Consequently, we already know its result : `"0 1 0 1 0 1"`. It could be more interesting to allow the user to pass these values as parameters to the function, like so :

```
function zeroCol(divisor, howMany) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
        arr.push(i % divisor);
    }
    return arr.join(' ')
}
```

Usage examples :

```
zeroCol(2, 4) // "0 1 0 1"
zeroCol(3, 4) // "0 1 2 0"
zeroCol(4, 4) // "0 1 2 3"
```

Comment: Making OP's life even more easier: `new Array(4).join('0 1 ')`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as though you return after the first iteration of your for loop.  That might be why it only prints 0.  It only executes the ternary operator once.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the operator; you are returning inside the loop, so it's returning after the first iteration through the loop. Place your return statement outside the loop:

```
function zeroCol(){
    var arr=[]
    for (var i=0;i<=5;i++){
        (i%2==0) ? arr.push(0) : arr.push(1);
    }

    return arr.join(" ");
}
console.log(zeroCol());
```